# Unable to connect CloudRun service to CloudSQL instance ( Nodejs-Express-Typeorm ) server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, typeorm, cloud-sql-proxy, google-cloud-run

I'm having issues connecting my node-express-typeorm server with CloudSQL Postgres instance using CloudRun.

I have successfully added the database proxy based on the official doc: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connect-cloudsql

And set environment variable for the express services as

`TYPEORM_URL=/cloudsql/[CONNECTION NAME]`

But the app is failing to start as its unable to connect to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The culprit was TypeORM. TypeORM is parsing database host from `TYPEORM_URL` using `/` delimiter. And it was only reading `cloudsql` instead of `/cloudsql/[CONNECTION NAME]`. So the app was unable to connect to the correct endpoint.

To fix the issue set the following environment variables instead of `TYPEORM_URL`

```
TYPEORM_HOST=/cloudsql/[CONNECTION NAME]

TYPEORM_USERNAME=<username>

TYPEORM_PASSWORD=<password>

TYPEORM_DATABASE=<db>
```

Comment: Hi @slovakyan, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @llompalles Hi, I'm sorry, I forgot doing that. Accepted :)